# Are there any links to meta on the home page now if you're not logged in?

Tags: discussion, questions

I just noticed while I was logged out that I cannot figure out any organic way to find the link to Meta Stack Overflow from the front page. Even clicking into questions, and around SO, I could find no way that I would discover meta SO on my own as an anonymous user.

Perhaps this has always been the way the site was - I can't remember because I'm very rarely logged out. Has it always been like this, or is it new with the homepage redesign? Is this by design (people without accounts shouldn't be looking at meta)? It's just curious - there was even a feature box for Meta SE, but not SO.

Comment: No. There isn't. I was using that a lot, but now I created a new 1 rep account to get to it quickly. Earlier if there were any featured posts, there used to be a link. Earlier than that, the site switcher was present in the top bar.

Comment: @BhargavRao yikes, that's not good. I remembered to try comparing it to StackExchange overall, and I see how much easier it used to be get to meta. The links are *all* different now

Answer (score 15):

Bhargav Rao's comment reminded me of what the top bar used to look like. A quick glance at Stack Exchange's top bar vs Stack Overflow's current one demonstrates the difference:

[image]

**VS**

[image]

The images pretty much speak for themselves.

Comment: We got rid of the important links to make room for selling the paid products.